# TemplateDoesNotExist at /index/

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

[web-browser error message IMAGE-click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGI9w.png)

First Django project.

I have created folder/Directory under application folder name **HTMLFile** inside this folder ***index.html*** is created.

Kindly help me pls.. Thanks in advance.
[Template configuration IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24g1C.png)

[Tree structure of project-django IMAGE-click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTejk.png)

Comment: Show us your templates configuration
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: Just added the image..@ iklinac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django looks for a `templates` directory under every installed app by default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

You should either:

- change the name of the directory from `HTLFile` to `templates`
- Configure the `TEMPLATES` under `settings.py` to include the `HTMLFile` dir

Comment: Thanks @Kroustou .. I have change the directory name to templates, it works fine now.

Comment: Please accept the answer as an approved solution.